# User input into Visualforce Template

Tags: visualforce-template

I want to send a VF Email template but I also want to have User inputted data.  Is this possible without creating an extra object to store this additional information on?

My Template will contain a parent object, but it will have a single child selected as well as specific grandchildren selected from that child.

I thought of 2 potential options if I cannot do this direct but I'd prefer not to use them.

1) Attach the item as a pdf that shares a controller with the page used to make the selections

2) Create an object to store all this information and run the template on this.

Comment: what sends the VF email template? apex code? workflow/process flow email alert? or OOB end user action 'send an email' button?

Comment: @cropredy Apex code in a VF page.

Comment: so , I must be missing something, but can't the user-input be saved in custom fields on parent object (or whatever object(s) the VF controller has access to?

Comment: No because there is a dynamic number of child objects it needs to bring information in about.  I could theoretically save all the ids comma delimited and then try to parse it in the template but I'm trying to void workarounds like that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, VF email templates can bring in values from either or both

a) object field values available through the `relatedTo` and `recipient` merge fields (basically, the target object and any of its relationships; the email destination Contact/Lead/User).  In effect, when the VF template is rendered, it has access to two controllers - one for `relatedTo` and one for`recipient`.

b) through the use of custom VF components and hence access to the VF custom component's controller getter properties / get methods. The custom component can be passed attribute values from the enclosing template - but in effect, this becomes values referenceable to `relatedTo` or `recipient` like `relatedTo.id`

Hence, any user input needs to be saved somewhere such that either the VF standard controllers or any custom controllers can access.